How to avoid second borrow in rust when iterating over mutable member of a struct and changing other members
I'm trying to write a code which borrow a mutable copy of the last member of a vector and then change another member of the vector. There is a check that the vector has more than 2 elements so there is no changes to the same element.
pub fn adjust(&mut self) {
    if self.vec.len() < 2 {
        return;
    }
    let vec_last = self.vec.last_mut().unwrap();
    let mut iter = vec_last.iter_mut();
    while let Some(i) = iter.next() {
        self.vec[0].push(i.clone());
    }
}

The compiler produces the error cannot borrow self.vec as mutable more than once at a time which is expected.
Is there a way to do such changes without triggering the error?
Cheers

You can split into two mutable slices:
pub fn adjust(&mut self) {
    if self.vec.len() < 2 {
        return;
    }
    let (first, rest) = self.vec.split_first_mut().unwrap();
    let last = rest.last().unwrap();
    for x in last {
        first.push(x.clone());
    }
}

